# First option from array is displayed as last in <ionic-select> tag when used with virtualScroll in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using a `<ion-select>` tag to display options to select from. If I use `virtualScroll` attribute with `<ion-select>`. Then the first item from array is displayed at last in the options list.

Below is the code I am using.

**Contents of home.html**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    Select an option
    <ion-select [virtualScroll]="items" bufferRatio="400">

        <ion-option *virtualItem="let item">{{item}}</ion-option>

    </ion-select>
</ion-content>
```

**Contents of home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  selector: 'home'
})

export class HomePage {
  items=[]
  constructor() {
    for(var i=1;i<=999;i++) {
      this.items.push(String(i))
    }
  }
}
```

Video displaying the issue:
https://vimeo.com/250773798

It is reproduced on stackblitz as well as on my machine. Sharing my machine info as well:

Link for reproducing the error - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-pupdfq?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

ionic info

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.17.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.17.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.4.0 ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
    Node       : v8.9.1
    npm        : 5.5.1 
    OS         : OS X El Capitan
    Xcode      : Xcode 8.2 Build version 8C38 

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```